# Bootstrap carousel images too big in mobile

Tags: css, carousel

I'm using bootstrap carousel on my site. When opened in a phone the images are huge. Take a look at www.nwberryfoundation.org to see what I mean. Is there a way to reduce the carousel in that view?

I've tried 
    @media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
      .carousel {
          width: 75%;
      }
    }

Doesn't seem to make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

Just use below code no need for media query and dont apply width instead try max-width

```
.carousel{
  max-width: 300px;  // u can changed it based on ur need or play with %
  margin: 0 auto;    // required to center div horizontally
}
```

[image]

Comment: glad I could help, if it worked for you you can marked it as answer thanks